# React 16.7 has State Hook,so I do not need react-redux anymore,is that right?

Tags: reactjs, redux

React 16.7 has State Hook,so I do not need react-redux anymore,is that right?

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding so far, Hook API is still not fully compatible with redux, and supporting for redux is [under development](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#what-do-hooks-mean-for-popular-apis-like-redux-connect-and-react-router). There is a [thread](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/issues/1063) in Github for the implementation of `useRedux` method.

Meanwhile, I think `react-redux` is still a better choice at the moment, since its API is already optimised for React app's performance. Implementing your own comparing function for re-rendering logic based on updates of redux store's data is too much for small & medium size projects.

Answer (score 1):

For global state still the react-redux is recommended way.

Use react-redux for disconnected components where need to access share state(global state).

Use react state for form-like components(local state)